# React Native Navigation Installing

Tags: react-native

Below is the error while installing react native navigation. help me to sort out this problem:

```
npm install -- save react-navigation
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path E:\ReactNative\logwithfirebase\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is
npm ERR! dest E:\ReactNative\logwithfirebase\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'E:\ReactNative\logwithfirebase\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\react-is' -> 'E:\ReactNative\logwithfirebase\node_modules\@react-navigation\core\node_modules\.react-is.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\asadc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T08_24_34_577Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete Installation for **React Native Navigation**

Install the React Navigation by following command.
`npm install @react-navigation/native`
After the installation Follow next steps:

**1.**`npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context`

If this doesn't work then
Remove the dependencies `@react-navigation/native` from **package.json**

Please remove your
`node_modules`
`package-lock.json`

and follow the same process again.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to run this ?
npm install @react-navigation/native

Ref:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Comment: yes after running npm install @react-navigation/native, it shows error.

Comment: Can you show me what command are you running in your terminal

Comment: npm install @react-navigation/native        this one i am using

Answer (score 0):

If you work on mac, that might be the reason. And you should run

```
yarn add @react-navigation/native
```